# Does every function have a graph?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble understanding this. My friend said it doesn't, but I disagree, though I'm not sure.

Given a function $f:A \to B$, the graph of $f$ is defined by $G(f) = \{(x,y)| x \in A , y = f(x)\}$. Then, is it true that if a function exists, its graph exist (Even though there may be no geometric interpretation)? I think this is true, since in the "worst" case it would be the empty set, which exists...

Comment: Of course it exists, by definition, just the way you described it. It can not be empty unless $A$ itself is empty. (At least, I assume that when one uses the notation $f:A\rightarrow B$, then one is implicitely stating that the domain of $f$ is $A$)

Comment: Correct. In set theory, [the graph **is** the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function).

Comment: There are cases, however, when a function cannot be *sketched* on a graph, like the [Dirichlet function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146078/321264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it exists.

If you are seeking to plot a function between 2 sets, you can plot $A$ on one axis, and $B$ on the other one and pick off the points as you mentioned.

In addition, if $A$ and $B$ are finite, you can draw $A$ and $B$ as points in space, and connect them via edges. You get $V = A \cup B$ with edges $E = \{(a,b) | f(a)=b\}$, which is also a representation with a graph, albeit quite a different one from the one you are describing.

Comment: How would you graph the function mapping every car in Utah to a licence plate number?  Would the domain  be a parking lot?

Comment: @WilliamElliot you make a representation mapping the VIN number to the index on the absciss and list the license plates as strings on the ordinate

Comment: So you use another function from cars to numbers that requires a parking lot domain so the first function would not need a parking lot.

Comment: @WilliamElliot for example. If you want to nitpick, the graph itself is also just a representation of the curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence can be looked at as a function as well...

Comment: If I cannot even plot a particular function, does that also mean that it's graph 'exists' in theory?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, any relation from a set  $A$ a set $B$ has a graph. Such a relation can be defined as a triple $(G,A,B)$ such that $G\subset A\times B$, and $G$ is the *graph* of the relation.

A *function* from $A$ to $B$ is just a relation $(G,A,B)$ such that, if $(x,y)$ and $(x,y')\in G$, then $\;y=y'$ (such a graph is called a *functional graph*).

A *map* from $A$ to $B$ is a function such that for each $x\in A$, there exists a (necessarily unique) $y$ such that $(x,y)\in G$.